# Entity Framework 7 Union Query error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This query works in EF6:

```
var ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var consultants = _dbContext.Times
    .Where(t => ids.Contains(t.MilestoneId))
    .Select(t => t.Consultant)
    .Union(
        _dbContext.TimeBudgets
            .Where(tb => ids.Contains(tb.MilestoneId))
            .Select(tb => tb.Consultant)
     );
```

In EF7, I get the error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
```

Comment: Do separated queries (without union) work?

Comment: Yes, without the union they're running fine.

Comment: Ok, you get error exactly on row `var consultants=..` or when you execute it as consultants.ToList()? And can you show your model's classes: Times, TimeBudgets? Also Entity Framework 7 is currently in pre-release, may you should wait stable version of it?

Comment: Hmm. On proper reading of the error, I see `NotImplementedException: Remotion.Linq.Clauses.ResultOperators.UnionResultOperator` - I take it it's not yet implemented in EF7?

Comment: You are not the only one, read this [post](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3459)

Comment: Ah, so it's an open issue. Ok, I suppose I should delete the question?

Comment: I think not (it can be useful for others), you can answer to yourself that it is EF7 bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be Not Implemented (yet).
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3459

Comment: Not sure if this affects you or not or if its viable, but you could spool the results via ToList or other means and then use a Union on the 2 results.